# Не могу разобраться с Null, как проверить что я ввел в консоль отрицательное число?

Tags: kotlin, null

Не могу разобраться с Null, как проверить что я ввел в консоль отрицательное число ?
Вообще необходимо посчитать сумму положительных чисел, я новичок в программировании с нуля, и в проверке  null не могу разобраться.

```
fun main() {
    println("Введите желаемое количество чисел: ")
    val number: Int? = readLine()?.toIntOrNull()
    val zero = 0
    if (number!=null) {
        println("Вы ввели число $number")
    }
    if (number < zero) {
        println("Вы ввели отрицательное число")
    }
    if (number==null) {
        println("Вы ввели не число")
    }
}
```

Comment: по логике внесите проверку на <0 внутрь условия != null, тогда падать не будет, и можно сделать вместо ==null просто else после условия != null, по поводу вопроса с проверкой отрицательности - у вас вроде есть такая проверка, в чем возникла проблема?

Comment: А он не хочет проверять...number < zero... выводит Operator call corresponds to a dot-qualified call 'number.compareTo(zero)' which is not allowed on a nullable receiver 'number'.

Comment: @Andrew, большое спасибо, реально затуп, тут не <0 а !=0 нужно было...

Comment: Добавьте `return` под каждым принтом. Или используйте `when`

Comment: если есть проверка ``number!=null``, то проверка ``number==null`` не нужна, т.к. если не выполняется ``!=``, то значит 100% ``==``

Comment: @Эникейщик, да большое спасибо много нюансов буду разбираться.

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov большое спасибо.

Comment: @Эникейщик... да про вывод вы правы... совсем я голову потерял с этим null... так как будет правильно...может подскажите...

Answer (score 1):

Вы же на Котлине пишете, компактнее надо и меньше if-ов.

```
number?.also {
    println("Вы ввели число $it")
    if (it < zero) {
        println("Вы ввели отрицательное число")
    } else {
        // тут считаем положительные
    }
} ?: println("Вы ввели не число")
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1321184/456831 Да этот код работает, но в моем условии also и it нет (я даже еще их не изучал), а так большое спасибо, реально работает код...

Answer (score 0):

Рабочий код, может кто подскажет где разжеван синтаксис (видимо это моя проблема)... я новичок, ведущего который дает волшебный пендель и направляет на путь истинный нет =)

```
fun main() {
    println("Введите желаемое количество чисел: ")
    val number: Int? = readLine()?.toIntOrNull()
    val zero:Int = 0
    number?.also {
        println("Вы ввели число $it")
        if (it < zero) {
            println("Вы ввели отрицательное число")
        } else {
            println("Вы ввели положительное число")
        }
    } ?: println("Вы ввели не число")}
```

Comment: Вот могу посоветовать: https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/mastering-kotlin-standard-functions-run-with-let-also-and-apply-9cd334b0ef84

Comment: Конструкция `number?.also { <code 1> } ?: { <code 2> }`по сути более элегантный заменитель классической `if (number != null) { <code 1> } else { <code 2> }`

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja большое спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

В исходном коде достаточно вторую проверку внести внутрь первой, тогда все будет работать

```
fun main() {
    println("Введите желаемое количество чисел: ")
    val number: Int? = readLine()?.toIntOrNull()
    val zero = 0
    if (number != null) {
        println("Вы ввели число $number")
        if (number < zero) {
            println("Вы ввели отрицательное число")
        }
    }
    else {
        println("Вы ввели не число")
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь (код работает), но все равно не доходит как посчитать сумму введенных положительных  чисел в консоль, причем количество введений чисел должен указывать пользователь...

Comment: создать цикл от от 1 до number, запрашивать числа и складывать

Answer (score 0):

Может новичкам пригодиться... Я его победил =) Мой рабочий код... По условию задачи необходимо:

1. Ввести число с клавиатуры в консоль.
2. Введите следующие числа, каждое с новой строки. Используйте для этого цикл. Начните итерацию цикла заново, если пользователь ввёл не число. Используйте для этого нуллабельные типы и elvis-operator.
3. Выведите в консоль количество введённых положительных чисел по окончании ввода чисел. Используйте if, чтобы проверить, что число положительное. Посчитайте сумму введённых чисел.

```
fun main () {
    print("Введите количество вводимых в консоль чисел: ")
    val number = inputNumbers()
    println("Желаемое количество чисел для ввода = $number")
    var mainNum = 0
    var sumAllNum = 0
    var sumPosNum = 0
    var sumAllPosNun = 0
    while (mainNum < number){
        println("Введите число: ")
        val numberString = readLine()?.toIntOrNull() ?: continue
        mainNum++
        sumAllNum += numberString
        if (numberString > 0) {
            sumPosNum++
            if (numberString > 0)
                sumAllPosNun += numberString
        }
    }
    println("Количество вводов чисел = $number ")
    println("Сумма всех чисел = $sumAllNum")
    println("Количество положительных чисел = $sumPosNum")
    println("Сумма положительных чисел = $sumAllPosNun")
    }

fun inputNumbers (): Int {
    return readLine()?.toIntOrNull() ?: inputNumbers()
}
```